# Highcharts tooltip between series points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-inverted/) for example, I want to be able to mouse over any position on the spline and show a tooltip presenting x and y, vs. only showing a tooltip for the predefined series data points as it currently works.  Is there such an option with Highcharts?

Only thing I see in the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cspline%3E) would be `followPointer` which keeps the tooltip on the pointer but the series data points are still selected.

```
series: {
    tooltip: {
        followPointer: true
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not a built in option. You will need to build your own mouseover and mouseout event callbacks.